# Add column to data frame using transform and calling a function -- an annoying weird behavior

Tags: r

***Reproducible and simplified example to explain my core question***:

I start with a function having a vector as argument, say: `fVec <- function(v) v[1]*v[2]`.

For comparison purposes, a direct way with explicit parameters to express the same function is: `fDirect <- function(a, b) a*b`.

In my use case, I want to build a function with explicit parameters like `fDirect` above but implement it by calling the initial function `fVec`.  So for this purpose, I defined: `fIndirect <- function(a, b) fVec(c(a, b))`.  (I explain below why I want to do something like that apparently not making any sense!)

As expected, `fVec(c(2, 3))`, `fDirect(2, 3)`, and `fIndirect(2, 3)` return 6, so far so good.

Now for plotting purposes, I build a data frame with the data I want to plot as follows:

1. Create the function parameter values: `mydf <- data.frame(a=1:3, b=2:4)`.
2. Add the function value in a new column using `transform`.

Using `fDirect`, `transform(mydf, v=fDirect(a, b))` does work as expected, it returns:

```
> transform(mydf, v=fDirect(a, b))
  a b  v
1 1 2  2
2 2 3  6
3 3 4 12
```

However, using `fIndirect`, it does not return the desired function values:

```
> transform(mydf, v=fIndirect(a, b))
  a b v
1 1 2 2
2 2 3 2
3 3 4 2
```

In debugging, I realized using `fIndirect`, `transform` passed to `fVec` a vector argument being the union of columns `a` and `b` of the data frame, that is: `c(mydf[["a"]], mydf[["b"]])`.  As a result, `fVec` did what it was programmed to do, that is evaluate the product of the first two elements, hence returning `1*2=2` for all rows.

So far, the best **solution** I could come up with to work around this `transform` challenge was using `apply` as follows:

```
cbind(mydf, v=apply(mydf, 1, function(row) fIndirect(row["a"], row["b"])))
```

***Question***:
Why does `transform` passes both data frame columns to `fVec` through `fIndirect` instead of behaving the same way as when calling it with `fDirect` where there it evaluates the function one row at a time?  Is it an R bug or do I misunderstand something fundamental in the way R works like perhaps something about scoping and/or argument casting?

***Context***:

This section explains why I follow such a process, perhaps someone can point out a better way to architect it.

I have a fairly complex objective function I try to optimize (i.e., `fVec` role).  This function has a variable number of parameters passed in as a named vector argument for convenience in the various ways I use this function, in particular the use of BBoptim optimizer that expects a vector as argument of the objective function.

In some cases where the number of variable parameters is 1 or 2, I want to plot my objective function (I use `plot` in 1-dim case; I use `levelplot` and `wireframe` from the lattice package in the 2-dim case).

So then, I build a temporary function with explicit parameters (i.e., `fIndirect` role) for convenience of building the data I want to plot into a data frame (i.e., `mydf` role).  Since my objective function is relatively complex and I need a version with a vector argument, I would like my temporary function `fIndirect` to be implemented by calling my original objective function `fVec`.

Can anyone propose a better way to accomplish the same goal than the process I showed in my simplified example above?

Comment: `transform` is behaving in exactly the same way (as documented, no bug) in both cases. You are overlooking _vectorized_ operations. Run `fDirect(1:3,2:4)`.

Comment: @joran Thanks much Joran, you made it clear how I misinterpreted the way R went about executing transform.  So then to use `transform`, the key is to implement `fIndirect` in such a way as to support vector arguments, for instance like: `fIndirect <- function(a, b) vapply(1:length(a), function(row) fVec(c(a[row], b[row])), FUN.VALUE=1)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I can mark this question as answered, credits to Joran, the key issue was not in `transform`; the problem was `fIndirect` did not support *vectorized* operations.

`fDirect` with vector arguments supporting vectorized operations:

```
fDirect(1:3,2:4)
[1]  2  6 12
```

`fIndirect` with the same vector arguments **NOT supporting** vectorized operations:

```
fIndirect(1:3,2:4)
[1]  2
```

It makes sense as `fIndirect(1:3,2:4) = fVec(c(1:3,2:4))`, that is the product of the first two elements.

My misconception was to believe that `transform(mydf, v=fct(a, b))` would call the function `fct` on every row of the data frame `mydf`, that is `fct(mydf[i, "a"], mydf[i, "b"])` for every row index `i` where each call would be with a pair of scalars.  I learned instead the new column `v` in the data frame was generated by calling the vectorized form of the function as `fct(mydf[["a"]], mydf[["b"]])`.  I missed this basic mode of operation in my self learning of R!

So a proper implementation of `fIndirect` to support *vectorized* operations could be something like:

```
fIndirect <- function(a, b)
  vapply(1:length(a), function(row) fVec(c(a[row], b[row])), FUN.VALUE=1)
```

Bottom line, when implementing a function, make sure to support vector arguments by looping through vector elements as need be **within** the function implementation!

Regarding the overall process in my context, I suppose it is fine.  As an alternative to code the process in R if there is no need to automate the process, I suppose one could perhaps *explore* and plot the data using some UI interactive packages like `Rcmdr`.

I hope the details of what I learned may be useful to someone.